# Cannot connect to ganache-cli with web3 and nodejs

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs, ganache

from package.json:

```
"ganache-cli": "^6.3.0",
"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.41",
```

in my createContract.js

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const ganache = require("ganache-cli");
console.log('ganache.provider :', JSON.stringify(ganache));
let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(ganache.provider()));
```

the result of the console log:

```
ganache.provider : {"_webpacked":true,"version":"2.4.0","to":{}}
```

my error:

```
.../node_modules/web3-providers/dist/web3-providers.cjs.js:99
    if (host.substring(0, 5) === 'https') {
             ^
TypeError: host.substring is not a function
```

any advice on this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use the ganache provider like this:

```
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
```

Comment: this way, I get: Error: Please provide an valid Web3 provider

Comment: See related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44522/using-ganache-cli-provider-causes-error-provider-not-set-or-invalid